# TRIGGERS-Updating a value in a table not updating Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Table description:
two tables
Product (Prodid, Prodesc, Price, Stock,Reord) 
Sales (Salesid, Proid, qty)

Question:
Create a Trigger which reduces the stock of Product that is been inserted in sales and update the stock when purchase is made.

I made a sample trigger only for purchase but my product's stock not updating.
This is my code.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger updat after
2  insert or update on product for each row
3  declare
4  temp number;
5  temp1 number;
6  temp2 varchar2(5);
7  begin
8  select qty into temp from purchase;
9  select proid into temp2 from purchase;
10  select stock into temp1 from product;
11  temp1:=temp1+temp;
12  update product set stock=temp1 where prodid=temp2;
13  end;
14  /
```

I am weak in Triggers. Help.

Comment: You need to write the trigger for the Sales table, no?  When a sale is entered you then need to update product.stock to remove qty based on prodid.

Comment: are u saying that i should replace tht "insert or update on product" as "insert or update on sales" ??

Comment: Yes, I would think so.  Your trigger code also references a "purchase"  table which you do not describe.  You mention "sales" table in the question.  Please be specific and consistent.

Comment: You can't `update` the table that is being changed by the trigger. And if you want to change the row of the `product` table you need a `before` trigger, not an `after` trigger. And your select statements are almost certainly wrong because they don't have a `where` clause and they will fail as soon as you have more than one row in those table. I suggest you re-read the Oracle manual regarding the concepts of triggers and PL/SQL

Comment: If any one could write the correct code for me please. I need it soon.

Comment: Please make sure whether am correct with the question. That is, if i add a new row in sales table,the quantity specified must be subtracted from the main "Product's" stock and other case is if i add a new row to purchase, i must add the corresponding qty to "Product's" stock. Right? I am telling that we need two updations: 1.Stock-qty(sales) 2.Stock+qty(purchase). Have i correctly understood the qn. ?

Comment: I need a code for it please help. I really need t soon.

Comment: @user3536847, this is NOT your codewriting service. If you don't know how to do this and flunk you class, that is a good thing.

Comment: I dont need a comment here who could not help me. I am asking the one's who could help me. No unnecessary comments needed . "HLGEM"

Comment: I needed the full coding. Please Help. As I mentioned I am really weak in triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger is a bit of a mess so it's hard to know quite where to start.  I'll make a number of guesses and assumptions-- I'll try to call them out but I'll probably miss one or two.

First, the trigger likely needs to be defined on the `sales` table.  You want to modify the `product` table in response to a change to the `sales` table.  Second, the requirement only appears to require an `after insert` trigger, it doesn't appear that you need to modify the `product` table when a row in `sales` is updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER INSERT ON sales
  FOR EACH ROW
```

Second, your variables are named exceptionally poorly.  Calling things `temp`, `temp1`, and `temp2` makes your code much harder to read and to write because you'll have no idea what any variables actually contain.  That makes it much harder to read the code and see what's going on let alone notice any bugs.  Always choose meaningful names.

Third, if you are going to write `select into` statements, you need to ensure that you are always selecting a single row.  That almost certainly requires a `WHERE` clause, most likely using one or more columns from the `:new` pseudorecord to determine which row you are interested in.  In this case, though, there doesn't appear to be a need to declare any local variables or to write any `select` statements.  It sounds like you just want to

```
UPDATE product
   SET stock = stock - :new.qty
 WHERE prodID = :new.prodID
```

If you want to enhance your trigger to handle updates to `sales` in addition to inserts, you would want to compute the difference between the `:old.qty` and the `:new.qty` and subtract that from the `stock` of the `product`.

Comment: really a useful one. Thank you very much. I will correct the mistakes. Your points were very clear and understandable. :)

Comment: Can u specify what kind of "where" clause must be added to select statement.?

Comment: @user3536847 - That depends on what you are attempting to select.  You need a `where` clause that ensures that your query returns exactly 1 row if you're going to use a `select into`.  As I said, there doesn't appear to be any need here to declare any local variables or to write any `select` statements.  If you decide to add a `select into`, you'd need to ensure that query returns exactly 1 row.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you are adding your qty with prodid. And the relation between the tables sales,product and purchase is not clear. From your description i think this would help.

```
 create or replace trigger TRIG_STOCK
 after insert or update on Sales
 for each row
 pragma autonomous_transaction;
 begin
 update product set stock=stock-:new.qty where prodid=:new.prodid;
 update purchase set qty=:new.qty where prodid=:new.prodid;
 commit;
 end;
```

Comment: First, the assignment operator in SQL is `=` not `:=` (`:=` would be correct if you were assigning a value in PL/SQL).  Second, never declare a trigger to be an `autonomous_transaction` unless it is simply doing something like writing to a log that you want preserved if the parent transaction rolls back.  Third, you wouldn't want to update the `purchase` table in this trigger.  Potentially, you'd want a separate trigger on `purchase` that also updates `product`.

Comment: qty from purchase differ from the qty of sales. And ur program did not help. Sorry.